# Google Mock giving compile error when attempting to specify a return value

Tags: c++, qt, boost, googletest, googlemock

I'm using Google Test and Google Mock for my C++/Qt application. I've been having great success with this setup until just now when I tried this:

```
QList<AbstractSurface::VertexRow> rowList;
for (unsigned i = 0; i < rows; ++i)
{
    AbstractSurface::VertexRow curRow(new AbstractSurface::Vertex[cols]);
    for (unsigned j = 0; j < cols; ++j)
    {
        curRow[j] = AbstractSurface::Vertex();
    }
    rowList.append(curRow);
}
ON_CALL(surface, numRows_impl()).WillByDefault(Return(rows));
ON_CALL(surface, numColumns_impl()).WillByDefault(Return(cols));
ON_CALL(surface, popAllRows_impl()).WillOnce(Return(rowList));
/* ... */
```

Attempting to compile this results in the following error message from gcc:

```
../../3DWaveSurface/test/TestWaterfallPresenter.cc: In member function ‘virtual void<unnamed>::WaterfallPresenterTest_CallingPaintGLCallsPaintRowForEachRowInSurface_Test::TestBody()’:
../../3DWaveSurface/test/TestWaterfallPresenter.cc:140:41: error: ‘class testing::internal::OnCallSpec<QList<boost::shared_array<AbstractSurface::Vertex> >()>’ has no member named ‘WillOnce’
```

If it helps, `VertexRow` is a `typedef` for a `boost::shared_array<Vertex>` and `Vertex` is a `struct` with a valid empty constructor.

Is this an error in what I wrote for the test or some incompatibility with using `QList` or `shared_array`?

---

**SOLUTION**
After following VJo's recommendation, my tests compiled and ran but then crashed:

```
Stack trace:
: Failure
Uninteresting mock function call - returning default value.
    Function call: popAllRows_impl()
    The mock function has no default action set, and its return type has no default value set.
The process "/home/corey/development/3DWaveSurface-build-desktop-debug/test/test" crashed.
```

Because there was no default return for `popAllRows_impl()`. I added a default:

```
ON_CALL(surface, popAllRows_impl()).WillByDefault(Return(QList<AbstractSurface::VertexRow>()));
```

To my `SetUp()` and all is well. As VJo pointed out, there is no WillOnce() for `ON_CALL` but there is for `EXPECT_CALL` and I missed this in the cook book..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest solution is :

```
EXPECT_CALL(surface, popAllRows_impl()).WillOnce(Return(rowList));
```

EDIT :

`ON_CALL` has `WillByDefault`, but no `WillOnce` method. Check the [gmock cookbook](http://code.google.com/p/googlemock/wiki/CookBook)

Comment: This actually worked (with one addition I did to my setup). Will post complete solution in original question.